# Cannot able to append to a global variable in a local function swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, global, local

This is my View Controller class

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var contact_Table: UITableView!

    var  contacts : [Contact] = [Contact]()
    var conj : [Contact] = [Contact]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.populate()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

func populate()
    {

        let urlstring = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/25976"

        let url = NSURL(string : urlstring)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data,response, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                var jsonerror : NSError?

                let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonerror)
                    as! NSDictionary

                if let  list_of_doctors = json["doctors"] as? NSArray{

                    let no_of_contacts = list_of_doctors.count-1
                    for index in 0...no_of_contacts
                    {
                        if let single_contact = list_of_doctors[index] as? NSDictionary{

                            let first_name = single_contact["first_name"] as? String               

                            let last_name=single_contact["last_name"] as? Strin                            

                            let password = single_contact["password"] as? String

                            var contactjson = Contact(online: "online_green_dot.jpeg", type: "iamge_nurse.png", name: first_name!, workplace_image: "hospital.png", designation: password!, workplace: last_name!)
                          contacts.append(contactjson)

                        }
                    }
                }
         })
    }
   task.resume()
```

Even though the contacts is a local variable, I am not able to append the data using contacts.append() It is asking me to use self.contacts.append()

Comment: `contacts` isn't local.  It is a property.  `self.contacts` is the appropriate refernece

Comment: Ya. But when i do that , Its creating a new instance  in the for loop but not appending to the existing contacts array

Comment: No, that isn't correct.  Are you perhaps trying to access the contacts array before the asynchronous task has completed?

Comment: Oh ya. Mabye thats the issue. Working on it now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler forces you to explicitly call `self` because `self` is **strongly** captured in a closure (implicitly by `contacts`). So you can clearly see that this call is an implicit reference to `self`. This also implies that you should consider making `self` a `weak` or `unowned` reference in a capture list:

```
// replace weak with unowned if self is always there/ not nil
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { [weak self] (data,response, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
```

Note that the array gets updated asynchronously after 0.85 seconds (at least for me). So you should make your update code (for the table view) in the closure to make sure that the `contacts` array is updated.

Comment: No. Thats not working. During runtime, It creates a new contact variable in the block and I m not able to retrieve it later.

Comment: @shreshtabm How do you know, that a new variable was created?

Comment: I have applied breakpoint. The data will get added to contacts but it's self.contacts n it won't be updated in contacts

Comment: @shreshta bm It seems that you access the contacts array too early. In fact the array gets updated after 0.85 seconds (at least for me). (So my point still remains and added a note)

Comment: I am not able refresh the tableView. Any idea Where to write tableVeiw.reload() ?

Comment: @shreshtabm After the for loop in the closure. So it gets updated as soon as the contacts array has all its contacts.